# find_if for nested tuple, return access to other tuple with same layout

Tags: c++, search, tuples, compile-time

I've two tuples of identical nesting and layout, but one tuple is read-only and contains only constant data, whereas the other one can change during runtime and is generally accessible by the user.

An example would be the following nested tuple, containing some (template) structs S which hold either two const strings and integers, or a single non-const integer. What stays the same, regardless of which tuple one wants to access, is the index_sequence to get to the desired value.

```
  constexpr auto tuple_r = std::make_tuple(

      std::make_tuple( S{
                          "description",
                          "first_name",
                          10,           // min
                          100           // max
                        }
                      ),

      std::make_tuple( S{
                          "description",
                          "second_name",
                          10,           // min
                          100           // max
                        }
                     )
  );

  auto tuple_rw = std::make_tuple(

      std::make_tuple( S{
                          42
                        }
                      ),

      std::make_tuple( S{
                          43
                        }
                     )
  );
```

So far so good. With a lot of useful tuple topics here on SO I've got most things I need covered, but one particular feature I'd like to add keeps bothering me. I'd like to search the const tuple for a specific name string and return whatever helps me access the non-const versions value on the very same position. So, using the example above, I'd like to access the value 42 by searching for "first_name".

In order to achieve that I've tried to write some "std::find_if" like function which recursively steps through the tuple and compares the string with a predicate. The general idea is straight forward and looks like this ->

(head is a simple get<0> wrapper and tail ... well, tail returns the tuple without head)

```
// recursion here
template<typename Head, typename Tail, typename F>
constexpr bool find_if_impl(Head&& head_, Tail&& tail_, F&& f)
{
  // call f(head_)
  // check possible recursion on head_
  // check possible recursion on tail_
}

// recursion here as well
template<typename T, typename F>
constexpr bool find_if_impl(T&& t, F&& f)
{
  return find_if_impl(head(t), tail(t), f);
}

// start
template<typename T, typename F>
constexpr bool find_if(T&& t, F&& f)
{
  return find_if_impl(t, f);
}
```

The problem is, currently my "find_if" acts more like an "any_of". I've tried keeping track of the index_sequence when stepping through tuple, but I simply can't return it because the trailing return type would change with each new index I add or remove...

Is there any solution to this? The only way I could think of so far which would keep "constexpr-ness" is to pass an array as another parameter and keep track of the indices there. Since I don't know the actual index sequence length in advance, the array would always have to be the size of the maximum tuple-depth.

Comment: Is there a requirement for you to use nested tuples? In the code above, it seems you can simplify things by using a tuple containing only a read only struct and a read-write struct. You could even use std::pair and use first/second to distinguish between access type.

Comment: The code is for an arm cortex m4 platform with a (relatively) small memory. Its less constness and accessibility I have in mind, but rather ram and flash constraints. Having two tuples, i can place one in ram and one in flash. I suppose thats not possible with a single std::pair type.